# Tahoma font rendering on Windows 8

Tags: c#, fonts, windows-8, gdi

Is there any way to render a Tahoma font text on Windows 8 like in previous Windows version? We are using the GDI Graphics.DrawString() in a WinForms application to draw it but the result looks much different. Characters are badly spaced.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you should always favor the TextRenderer class.  It fixes the pretty broken behavior of Graphics.DrawString() on low DPI devices like monitors.  TextRenderer.DrawText() uses the GDI's DrawTextEx() winapi function, same function as used by many native Windows programs to render text.

A good demonstration of the difference between the two is this sample form:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) {
        var s = "Hiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii";
        e.Graphics.DrawString(s, this.Font, Brushes.Black, 0, 0);
        TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, s, this.Font, new Point(0, this.Font.Height), Color.Black);
        base.OnPaint(e);
    }
}
```

On a 96 dpi monitor that looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Text renderer does not support transparency (to draw a black text on a transparent bitmap), do you know any workaround for this?

Comment: It does.  Click the Ask Question button to document your new question properly.

Comment: The problem is that if you draw a white string on a transparent background bitmap the antialiasing is done in black instead of modulating the alpha channel...

Comment: Yes, Color.Transparent is black with an alpha of 0.  There is no text rendering engine on Windows that "modulates" the alpha.  Pointless anyway because the background color is entirely unpredictable, it can never anti-alias the text properly.  You must turn off anti-aliasing.